# Setting all theme elements blank does not affect the axis elemenets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the dataframe below

```
GO<-c("cytosol (GO:0005829)","cytosol (GO:0005829)")
FE<-c(2.70,4.38)
FDR<-c(0.00159,0.00857)
Facet<-c("ileum 24h","ileum 72h")
CCC<-data.frame(GO,FE,FDR,Facet)
```

and with this code

```
CCC %>%
  arrange(desc(CCC$GO))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = FDR, y = GO, size = FE, color = FDR)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_size(range = c(5, 8), name = "Fold enrichment") + 
  facet_grid(cols = vars(Facet), scales = "free") + 
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_y_discrete(name = "GO biological process complete") +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "FDR") +
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "red", name  = "FDR") + 
  theme_bw()
```

I create a bubble plot with facets. But I want to delete the `x-axis` title 'FDR' and display the labels with an angle but despite setting the `theme()` it does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put `theme_bw()` at the end, which over-writes your `theme` call. Put your custom themes at the end:

```r
CCC %>%
  arrange(desc(CCC$GO))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = FDR, y = GO, size = FE, color = FDR)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_size(range = c(5, 8), name = "Fold enrichment") + 
  scale_y_discrete(name = "GO biological process complete") +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "FDR") +
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "red", name  = "FDR") +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(Facet), scales = "free") + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

I think it is good practice to lay out your calls to ggplot in a consistent way so that this kind of thing doesn't happen:

1. Call ggplot +
2. Geom (and stat) layers, ordered depending on which ones you want on top +
3. Scales +
4. Facets +
5. Labels and titles +
6. Global themes like `theme_bw()` +
7. Individual theme tweaks via `theme`

Answer (score 1):

Only change the position of `theme_bw()`:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
GO<-c("cytosol (GO:0005829)","cytosol (GO:0005829)")
FE<-c(2.70,4.38)
FDR<-c(0.00159,0.00857)
Facet<-c("ileum 24h","ileum 72h")
CCC<-data.frame(GO,FE,FDR,Facet)
#Plot
CCC %>%
  arrange(desc(CCC$GO))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = FDR, y = GO, size = FE, color = FDR)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_size(range = c(5, 8), name = "Fold enrichment") + 
  facet_grid(cols = vars(Facet), scales = "free") +
  xlab('')+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_y_discrete(name = "GO biological process complete") +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "") +
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "red", name  = "FDR")
```

Output:

[image]